# How to disable proxy server cache?

Tags: http, caching, proxy, browser-cache, cache-control

Our customer used proxy to visit our service like this:

```
Browser <--> Proxy Server <--> Our Service
```

The proxy server was build by the customers themselves and will cache our http content(html, ActiveX control etc.). When we update the content, the customer's browser gets the old version from proxy server until the proxy server cache the newer version. The cache strategy is not controllable by us. So I want to ask are there any technologies to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find a comprehensive answer to your question in https://stackoverflow.com/q/49547/1878585

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Start, click Run, type gpedit.msc, and then click OK.
2. In Group Policy Object Editor, double-click User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer.
3. Double-click Disable caching of Auto-Proxy scripts.
4. Double-click Disable caching of Auto-Proxy scripts.

Comment: Will this method disable cache in proxy server?